# Перебор элементов в Tuple

Tags: python

Начал только изучать Python и не могу решить одну задачу. 
Получаю данные с базы  такого вида

```
[('192.168.3.4', 'Склад Феникс-Презент'), ('192.168.0.34', 'Старый офис'), ('192.168.2.3', 'Склад ТД Феникс')]
```

хочу пинговать эти адреса с определенной периодичностью и как только возникнет обрыв, пишем сообщение об этом событии

```
print(Склад Феникс-Презент + " нет связи")
```

Так вот у меня проблемы с перебором этого списка

```
def ping_Remote():
    while True:
         with sqlite3.connect('FenixLite.db') as db:
             cursor = db.cursor()
             cursor.execute('SELECT IPAdr, IPLocation FROM IPList')
             ipList = cursor.fetchall()
             print(ipList)
             i = 0
             r = 1 
         while ipList:
              print(ipList[i][i])
              response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ipList[i][i]]).wait()
              if response != 0:
                  print(ipList[i][r] + " нет связи")
              i = i + 1
              r = r + 1
              time.sleep(10)

ping_Remote()
```

Попрошу знатоков поправить код, так как вполне очевидно он бездарен.
Просто уже то, что вызов базы происходит в начале функции и затем никак не вызывается приведет к проблеме обновления этого листа, то есть программа в вечно запущенном состоянии не будет знать о произошедших изменениях в базе??

И еще возникла проблема с перебором как сделать так,чтобы айпи адрес и локация
перебирались в цикле правильно? В моем случаи код работает одну итерацию адекватно, а потом пишет, что вышел за индекс. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `while ipList`

```
for item in ipList:
   ip = item[0]
   name = item[1]
   # или ip, name = item
   # дальше делаете то, что Вам нужно
```

И никаких индексов i, r - не нужно

Answer (score 0):

тут есть 2 самых нормальных решения:
`for i in iplist:`
мы проходим по списку, и с каждой новой итерацией, тоесть повторением цикла i меняется на следующий обьект в списке.
`print(i)` вернет сначала первый обьект, потом второй  и тд.
хочу подметить, что в это варианте мы не имеем доступа к номеру обьекта, но мы его можем найти: `list.index(list, object)`.
или можем поступить разумнее, написав это:
`for i in range(len(iplist)):`
данный пример превращает i не в обьект из списка, а его номер. для доступа к обьекту, надо написать `iplist[i]`. тут есть срезы, они работают так:
к примеру возьмем список `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`:

```
print(l[0]) #тут мы взяли первый элемент, да, в Python подсчет начинается с нуля. вернет 1
print(l[0:6]) #тут мы взяли от первого элемента, до шестого. вернет [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#ну а дальше можешь почитать в https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html
```